# Woocommerce Checkout Errors

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, e-commerce, fatal-error

I am having some issues with my woocommerce store. Clients are experiencing trouble when checking out. They fill in all the required fields, and check the t’s & c’s – but then receive a ‘blank woocommerce error’ showing only a red exclamation mark with no error message.

I have tried the checkout from my end and am able to place orders, however many clients are having this problem.

Here are the ‘fatal errors’ in my woocommerce log:

```
2021-02-03T02:07:38+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(159): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product))
#1 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(135): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product))
#2 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-time-based-pricing/classes/com/WCTBP_Cart.php(42): WC_Product->__construct(2991)
#3 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): WCTBP_Cart->cart_add_to_validation(true, 2991, 1, '', Array)
#4 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
#5 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(902): apply_filters('woocommerce_add...', true, 2991, 1, '', Array)
#6 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/ in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 166

2021-02-03T02:13:39+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(159): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product))
#1 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(135): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product))
#2 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-time-based-pricing/classes/com/WCTBP_Cart.php(42): WC_Product->__construct(3024)
#3 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): WCTBP_Cart->cart_add_to_validation(true, 3024, 1, '', Array)
#4 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
#5 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(902): apply_filters('woocommerce_add...', true, 3024, 1, '', Array)
#6 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/ in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 166

2021-02-03T02:27:02+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(159): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product))
#1 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(135): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product))
#2 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-time-based-pricing/classes/com/WCTBP_Cart.php(42): WC_Product->__construct(2999)
#3 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): WCTBP_Cart->cart_add_to_validation(true, 2999, 1, '', Array)
#4 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
#5 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(902): apply_filters('woocommerce_add...', true, 2999, 1, '', Array)
#6 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/ in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 166

2021-02-03T05:18:25+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(159): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product))
#1 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(135): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product))
#2 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-time-based-pricing/classes/com/WCTBP_Cart.php(42): WC_Product->__construct(3066)
#3 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): WCTBP_Cart->cart_add_to_validation(true, 3066, 1, '', Array)
#4 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
#5 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(902): apply_filters('woocommerce_add...', true, 3066, 1, '', Array)
#6 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/ in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 166

2021-02-03T07:28:12+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(159): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product))
#1 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(135): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product))
#2 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-time-based-pricing/classes/com/WCTBP_Cart.php(42): WC_Product->__construct(3066)
#3 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): WCTBP_Cart->cart_add_to_validation(true, 3066, 1, '', Array)
#4 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
#5 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php(902): apply_filters('woocommerce_add...', true, 3066, 1, '', Array)
#6 /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/ in /usr/www/users/cherrfqzxc/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 166
```

I have :

- Updated all plugins
- Updated the theme
- Checked the system status / health report, no issues are showing other than inactive plugins to be removed

Is the problem being caused purely by Woocommerce, or by the theme, or a conflict between Woocommerce and the theme?

[Link to Site](https://cherryblossomstore.co.za/)

Answer (score 1):

Those things can happen, as far as I can see it is a product that is invalid, have you checked the information about the product and did you use normal characters in the information when you made the product?

If everything is correct maybe check the database, and see if the product that you have added has all the right values in the database, if so maybe a rollback to the previous version of Woocommerce will fix the problem.

Let me know,

Jeff

Comment: thank you.  is there way to see which product is being referred to in the error?

Comment: @ultramel1987 I would say it is from here difficult to say what product makes the error, what can be a thing is that because if I am correct looking at the errors that you are using Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing, that uses a lot of values, try disable it on a test environment and try it again, also try this add this in functions.php.       add_filter('woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_get_decimals', 'custom_woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_get_decimals');
function custom_woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_get_decimals($decimals) {
return 4;
}